# QR code reader for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, components, qr-code

Is there a BlackBerry library/component (open source or commercial) for integration in my own application that acts as QR code reader? I'd like to fully integrate it in my application.

Or alternatively: is there a way to use the open source [ZXing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) in combination with the camera, ideally with live detection of the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're targeting BlackBerry 6, RIM has now included the ZXing library as part of the OS:

http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/10/barcode-api/

For pre-6.0.0 applications, the webpage for the zxing project mentions JavaME and RIM-specific modules:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

(Some of my coworkers have been able to integrate barcode generators into BlackBerry 5.0.0 applications using this library, so it's definitely possible to use zxing. But they haven't tried integrating with the camera for live detection.)