# QR-Code source that works on Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, mobile, qr-code, zxing

i'm trying to develop an app that integrates the qr code reader as part of the functionality.

i have read about zxing as the best option. but it turns out that they dont support development for blackberry, and the sample app shipped in zxing haves bugs (gives JVM runtime exception).

i wonder if anyone knows a viable alternative to use a reader without having to recreate all the app/cam/decoder functions from scratch.

thanks!.

Comment: See [
QR code reader for BlackBerry
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289753/qr-code-reader-for-blackberry).

Answer (score 4):

The new 6.0 APIs have native QR code support built in.  Judging from the package names ("com.google.zxing.qrcode") it looks like they just used the Google zxing library.  So maybe the library isn't as buggy as it used to be?

Comment: yes i saw those packages in the blackberry dev site. the thing is i'm having problems running the client sample app they provided (which is large enough to mess with it without having much experience developing for BB).

Comment: i just would like to know about anyone succesfully running this or any other sample app with code available and decoding qr without problems. that will be a better way to start.

Answer (score 2):

Developer here. To be clear, the library is in no sense buggy. The core decoding library is in fact built into BBOS 6.0 by RIM.

The sample app you cite merely does not support the version of the BBOS you are trying to use. And, there's nobody making a version for BBOS 6.0.

But, you are writing your own app right? Then you would not be using this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found this on BB dev forum: 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-the-Barcode-API/ta-p/574569

trying that now. if anyone knows, i appreciate advice.
this is for 6.0 API.

still looking for more compatibility. (most of current bb devices are previous 6.0).

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it working on the simulator for BB 6.0.

there was an error in a file reference call.
if anyone interested, the issue and the solution is reported on the zxing page/group.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=548&can=1&sort=-priority&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary

now i'm trying to run it on 5.0 but i'm having a problem with the compilation. 
well, that's another story...

Comment: I was in the same situation as you. Got it work on BB 6, spent some time on BB 5 but gave up with no luck. Does anyone has any updates?