# qr reader in blackberry example

Tags: blackberry, java-me, qr-code, zxing

I am workin on BB app and I need to implement QR reader or scanner into it. I know that RIM supported a library of it in OS6 and in ZXing but actually I need to read an example of how can I implement it within my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [QR code reader for BlackBerry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289753/qr-code-reader-for-blackberry)

Answer (score 3):

You can get a clear idea to how to develop a qr code in OS 6.0 From This [KB Article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-the-Barcode-API/ta-p/574569)

If you Try to develop It in OS 5.0 http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.com/2011/05/barcode-scanner-for-blackberry-os-50.html will help you.